# Chrome, colspan and border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have fairly simple HTML table, with one of the rows having a `td` with `colspan` attribute. The `border-bottom` applied on the corresponding `tr` doesn't affect across the `colspan`, but only affects the unspanned column. This happens only in chrome.

Sample code highlighting this issue. Observe the `Recent Items` row doesn't have the border across the entire row in chrome.

```css
.x1hu {
  height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.x1hw {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 28px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DFE6;
}
.x1hs {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.x1hx {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table role="grid" class="x1hs" aria-rowcount="5">
    <tr class="x1hw">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th><span style="font-style:italic">Specializations</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hx">
      <td colpsan="4">Recent Items</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item0" aria-rowindex="1" data-afr-value="469">
        <td>Lester Shull</td>
        <td>Analyst</td>
        <td>Lester.Shull@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">filing, fresher, physio, </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item1" aria-rowindex="2" data-afr-value="299">
        <td>Jennefer Patrick</td>
        <td>Contractor</td>
        <td>Jennefer.Patrick@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item2" aria-rowindex="3" data-afr-value="2072">
        <td>Alexis Prentice</td>
        <td>Contractor</td>
        <td>Alexis.Prentice@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">support, veteran, ERT, </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item3" aria-rowindex="4" data-afr-value="4641">
        <td>Hyun Mathias</td>
        <td>Supervisor</td>
        <td>Hyun.Mathias@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item4" aria-rowindex="5" data-afr-value="3900">
        <td>Douglas Hildreth</td>
        <td>Manager</td>
        <td>Douglas.Hildreth@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">mentor, </span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You made a typo: here `<td colspan="4">` you wrote **colpsan**

Comment: @Banzay Yes, you are right

Comment: Oh! That's it, it worked. I can't believe it was just this. Thanks!

Comment: @Banzay do you want to answer the question, so that I can accept the answer? Or since this Q is of no use for anybody in future, do I just delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo: here `<td colspan="4">` you wrote **colpsan**

```css
.x1hu {
  height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.x1hw {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 28px;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D6DFE6;
}
.x1hs {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.x1hx {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table role="grid" class="x1hs" aria-rowcount="5">
    <tr class="x1hw">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Contact Email</th>
        <th><span style="font-style:italic">Specializations</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hx">
      <td colspan="4">Recent Items</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item0" aria-rowindex="1" data-afr-value="469">
        <td>Lester Shull</td>
        <td>Analyst</td>
        <td>Lester.Shull@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">filing, fresher, physio, </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item1" aria-rowindex="2" data-afr-value="299">
        <td>Jennefer Patrick</td>
        <td>Contractor</td>
        <td>Jennefer.Patrick@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item2" aria-rowindex="3" data-afr-value="2072">
        <td>Alexis Prentice</td>
        <td>Contractor</td>
        <td>Alexis.Prentice@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">support, veteran, ERT, </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item3" aria-rowindex="4" data-afr-value="4641">
        <td>Hyun Mathias</td>
        <td>Supervisor</td>
        <td>Hyun.Mathias@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="x1hu" id="dmoTpl:iSearch2::item4" aria-rowindex="5" data-afr-value="3900">
        <td>Douglas Hildreth</td>
        <td>Manager</td>
        <td>Douglas.Hildreth@acme.com</td>
        <td><span style="font-style:italic">mentor, </span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```